# Java and Python App/Service Communication with Web Interface

Tags: java, python, web-services

Currently I have a Java (and a half ported python version) app that runs in the background that has a queue of jobs (currently read out of a mysql database) which handles thread sleep/waking to share resources based on the job priority and running time. There is a front end php script that posts jobs to the database which are polled by the system every time interval.

This manner is somewhat inefficient (but nicer than locking issues using a job file) but I can't but wonder if there would be some way to simplify this.

My thoughts were java app (and or python app) sets up http service (jetty?) and has a web interface that directly pushes jobs to the queue without the middleman. Apache is serving other php sites so this would have to run in tandem.

I'm really after some other input as I'd prefer it to be a background service always running - having a cron execute jobs was painful (since some jobs run for 20+ hours so adding new ones was a pain with new php [ no threading] /java calls having to check if a service was running with outstanding jobs to add to instead of starting a new service) but also have a very simple web interface without too much resource wastage.

Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 0):

Deploy a JSP using Tomcat (or similar) that allows the user to post job requests to a job scheduler web service using a webpage. On the backend, use [Quartz Scheduler](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/) to manage your jobs and just have your web service add jobs to the Quartz queue.